# Athena: Create view on information_schema

Tags: amazon-athena, information-schema

This works perfectly :

```
select i.* 
from information_schema.tables i
```

But this fails:

```
create view myschema.test
as
select i.* 
from information_schema.tables i
```

line 3:15: Schema information_schema does not exist

I also tried fully qualified:

```
AwsDataCatalog.information_schema.tables
```

... still no joy!
.. so am I missing something obvious ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Encountering the same

Comment: No I'm afraid not. Something I will still need to come back to, but got beaten by other priorities just now :(

Answer (score 0):

if you execute a create table XXX as select * from information_schema.tables it works and you can use it in another views